# How to create an animation from left to right or making a fade Angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, types

I want when the component is open to make an animation or to make a fade.

This is the code

This is the HTML

```
<div *ngIf="showMePartially" class="container">
  <div class="body-container">
</div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    transition: 3s;
}
.body-container {
  width: calc(100% - 73em);
  position: relative;
  left: 70em;
  top: 7.5em;
  background: white;
  height: calc(100% - 18em);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding-left: 11px; 
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular (4, 5, 6) - Simple example of slide in out animation on ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248898/angular-4-5-6-simple-example-of-slide-in-out-animation-on-ngif)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417931/angular-2-ngif-and-css-transition-animation

Comment: I will show that answer

Comment: nope didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use css animation:

```
.body-container {
   /* above styles */
   animation: animation-name .3s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes animation-name {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

You can make your own animation inside of keyframes. This should work, because `*ngIf` will either remove element from dom, if condition is false, or append it into dom(this is when animation should work).

**EDIT**
For left to right animation you can do like:

```
@keyframes animation-name {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working man you saved me, but how can I do from right to left the animation ?

Comment: Just change animation to : @keyframes animation-name {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

Comment: I didnt understand ?

Comment: Bro do you have any idea when I close the dialod to create also animation